# Creating Sequential-Access File - problem with scanf

Tags: c

This code snippet is from C How to Program (6th Edition Deitel), and is about creating a Sequential-Access File

It compiles fine but when executing the questionmark ? does not appear on the third row and only the first four rows are written to the file

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

int account;
char name[30];
double balance;

FILE *cfPtr;

if ((cfPtr = fopen("clients.dat", "w")) == NULL) {

    printf("File could not be opened\n");



}
else {

    printf("Enter account, name and balance.\n");
    printf("Enter EOF to end input\n");
    printf("?");
    scanf("%d%s%lf", &account, name, &balance);

    while (!feof(stdin)) {

        fprintf(cfPtr, "%d %s %.2f\n", account, name, balance);
        printf("?");
        scanf("%d%s%lf%", &account, name, &balance);


    }

    fclose(cfPtr);

}

return 0;
```

}

program in action (cmd)

```
 Enter account, name and balance
 Enter EOF to end input
 ? 100 Jones 24.98
 ? 200 Doe 345.67
 300 White 0.00
 ? 400 Stone -42.16
 ? 500 Rich 224.62
```

You can see when it comes to input the third row, there is no questionmark, and in the file the last row is missing

```
 100 Jones 24.98
 200 Doe 345.67
 300 White 0.00
 400 Stone -42.16
```

Any idea what is wrong with the code? input/outputstream-buffer?

Using MinGW

Comment: Please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) Secondly, always check the return value from `scanf` (the number of items successfully scanned), and that is what you should be using to control the loop: `while(scanf("%d%s%lf%", &account, name, &balance) == 3) {...}`

Comment: @WeatherVane - thanks, tried that but the problem is still there

Comment: You have an error in `"%d%s%lf%"` where the final specifier is incomplete (which I copied into my first comment). Watch out for compiler warnings.

Comment: ...but I can't reproduce your error anyway.

Comment: So the program works on your platform? What compiler are you using?

Comment: MSVC on Windows 7, from a console. It a little reluctant to respond to the Ctrl-Z EOF control, but no extra is added to the output. Even using your original code, where actually this is one of the few correct uses of `feof` (but still better not to).

Comment: ok - just a wild guess - I am using a 32bit compiler on a 64 bit platform .. could possibly cause the problem?

Comment: No, I think not.

Comment: @java, it happened to me also, at the third input was  I missing a ?, after I removed the extra `%` it was solved.

Comment: ... and it makes sense since the first sequence is outside the loop and doesn't have the extra `%`, the second is inside, so the problem only becomes apparent in the third input.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't replicating for me either.

What if you fflush?

EG:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    int account;
    char name[30];
    double balance;

    FILE *cfPtr;

    if ((cfPtr = fopen("clients.dat", "w")) == NULL) {
        printf("File could not be opened\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        printf("Enter account, name and balance.\n");
        printf("Enter EOF to end input\n");

        for (;;) {
            printf("?");
            fflush(stdout);
            if (scanf("%d%s%lf", &account, name, &balance) != 3) {
                break;
            }
            fprintf(cfPtr, "%d %s %.2f\n", account, name, balance);
        }

        fclose(cfPtr);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
scanf("%d%s%lf%", &account, name, &balance);
              ^
```

You have a `%` too many. That is the source of the `?` problem.

That said, this is a clumsy piece of code, especially being in a book.

If the input is wrong, let's say you input only one of the tree fields it fails to read resulting in an infinite loop, both in writing the last sequence to the the file and printing `?`.

Somenthing like

```
//...
else
{
    printf("Enter account, name and balance.\n");
    printf("Enter EOF to end input\n");
    do {
        fprintf(cfPtr, "%d %s %.2f\n", account, name, balance);
        printf("?");
    } while (scanf("%d%s%lf", &account, name, &balance) == 3);

    fclose(cfPtr);
}
//...
```

Would be an improvement.